# Get one element with Angular2 in a table in the backend Java EE

Tags: java, angular, jakarta-ee, frontend, backend

I try to make an application with Angular2 for the FrontEnd and JavaEE for the BackEnd. By following some demo, I finally understand how the data are exchange but I got a little issue when I want to recoup one element in a table.

The code in the person.service.ts :

```
export class PersonService {
private baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8080/SWBackend/jaxrs';

constructor(private http: Http) {}

  get(id: number): Observable<Person> {
    let person$ = this.http
      .get(`${this.baseUrl}/Person/${id}`, {headers: this.getHeaders()})
      .map(mapPerson);
      return person$;
  }

private getHeaders() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return headers;
  }
}


function mapPerson(response: Response): Person {
  return toPerson(response.json());
}

function toPerson(r: any): Person {
  return r;
}
```

in my person.component.ts :

```
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit{
    people: Person[] = [] ;
    pre: Person;

    constructor(private personService: PersonService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.personService
        .get(5)
        .subscribe(p => this.pre = p);
       this.personService.getAll().subscribe(p => this.people = p);
       // I get another method getAll who list all the people 
       // and works with almost the same code as get
    }
}
```

in my template, I did this :

```
<p> {{pre.id}}</p>
```

and I got this type of error :

```
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

and to conclude, at the adress "http://localhost:8080/SWBackend/jaxrs/Person", I have my list of person, so it's good, and at "http://localhost:8080/SWBackend/jaxrs/Person/5" I have the person I want, but I don't understand why I can't display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<p> {{pre?.id}}</p>
```

sometimes it will take some time to get data from database and view will render before so angular will throw an error like this.

By using `?` angular will not allow to throw any error even if data is not present there

Comment: Yes that's why I was thinking (about the time to get the data) but I didn't know if there was anything like the ? to wait for it.

Thanks for the answer, it works now :)